# iOS Swift PDFKit Widget Subtype button border

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

I'm working with PDFKit, and I'm looking to add a PDF Annotation that supports the user selecting/deselecting it.  I'm using *PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype.button* and I can't find a way to remove the border.  I've tried subclassing *PDFBorder* to no avail, has anyone else has experience with this?

[image: Checkbox with border]

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

My solution to this problem was to create my own PDFAnnotation subclass.

```
var isChecked = false

init(forBounds bounds: CGRect, withProperties properties: [AnyHashable : Any]?)

override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, in context: CGContext)
```

I used the *isChecked* property inside of the draw function.  If the property was toggled on, then I was display a checkmark image I found on Icons8.  I also had to add the PDFAnnotationHitObserver in my ViewController, and handled updating the property of isChecked.